# Ajax How do I send a form without it reloading

Tags: php, html, ajax

My current code that i have on my website is the following at the bottom, I will be soon transfering that code onto my profile.php :)

Test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$("#ntb").click(function() {
var nt = $("#nt").val();
var data=$('#nt').serialize();
if(nt=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../ajax/post.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});

</script>


<form method="post" name="form">
<input id="nt" name="nt" type="text" />
<input type="submit" style="display:block;" name='ntb' id='ntb'  class="Buttonchat"     value="Post" />
</form>
<div>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
</div></form&gt;
```

This code above is the ajax and html and dont really work when i have the ajax in but when i have just the html and php it posts into the database, idk why though :(

../ajax/post.php

```
<?php

include '../core/init.php';

if(isset($_POST['nt']) && isset($_POST['ntb'])){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `post` (`myid`, `text`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."',         '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nt'])."')");
}
?>
```

Above is my php to post the data, this works 100% :)
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
function submitMe(val) {
    jQuery(function($) {    
        $.ajax( {           
            url : "some_php_page.php?action="+val,
            type : "GET",
            success : function(data) {
                alert ("works!"); //or use data string to show something else
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Then I just parse the `action` in `some_php_page.php?`

Do it this way:

```
//function that get value from the request object and parses it to a variable; or stopps the script if no value is found
function getanyValue($param) {
    if (isset($_GET[$param])) {
        return $_GET[$param];
    } else {
        die('');
    }
}
//get the action value
$action = getanyValue('action');
//add action to the database
$inserId = addAction($action);

public $dbserver = '';
public $dbusername = '';
public $dbpassword = '';
public $dbname = '';

function openDb() {
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("error, please try again");
    }
    return $db;
}

function addAction($action) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO action_table (action_column) VALUES(?)";
    $db = $this->openDb();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $action, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    //get the action_table id from the database from the new insert
    return $db->lastInsertId('id');
}
```

Comment: Yes but how do i get it so it can post straight through to the database without having to make the page reload?

Comment: I added more code; `some_php_page.php`.
PS-  Do no forget to add reputation to users who help you and accept the correct answer when you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need AJAX to submit a form without reloading. A handy trick is to simply submit into a hidden iframe:

```
<iframe style="display:none" name="submissiontarget" id="submissiontarget"></iframe>

<form method="post" target="submissiontarget" action = "../ajax/post.php" name="form">
<input id="nt" name="nt" type="text" />
<input type="submit" style="display:block;" name='ntb' id='ntb'  class="Buttonchat"     value="Post" />
</form>
<div>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do i need to add anything else to that code to enable it to work?

Comment: @KaniRobinson Nope. It is important to note that your JS won't work anymore, but then you don't really need it.

Comment: @KaniRobinson Did you try it out?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing 'dataString' to the PHP script. What I can see 'dataString' is not defined anywhere.

So what you would've to do is:

```
var dataString = 'nt=' + data + '&ntb=whateverntbshouldbeequalto';
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score -1):

first i would try to print out your `$_POST` to see what is being sent. it seems your data is not formated correctly. you are testing for two seprate variables in your php but it seems you are trying to send only one in youre `data` section of the ajax post.